# point to next address in memory ( MIPS )

Tags: assembly, mips

I give 4 space for integer in my code and I want to add ( 4 ) to pointer for pointing to the next int
For example :

```
     .date
int:     .space 4

.text
main:
addi $t2,$t2,4
addi $t3,$t3,2
syscall
sw $t2,$int
syscall
      #now I want to add 4 to int for next integer that it is in $t3
```

How Can I do That?
Thanks

Comment: There's no next integer. `.space 4` reverves 4 _bytes_ of space, which is enough for _one_ 32-bit integer.

Comment: To add an immediate to a register, use `addi`. Consult the MIPS instruction set reference.